# Trying to use output of a layer as an input to another layer.(KERAS tensorflow backend)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm, conv-neural-network

I using Keras with Python 3. 
I am trying to apply the network shown in the attachment[model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1pcL.jpg). The sequential model does not help me because the order of my model is shuffled. For example, the output of X1 is used into Y1 and X2. My code looks

```py
conv1= (Convolution3D(32, 3, 3, 3, activation='relu', 
border_mode='same', name='conv1',
input_shape=(patch_size, img_rows, img_cols,3)))

input_1=conv1.output

lstm1=(ConvLSTM2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3),
padding='same', return_sequences=True))(input_1)

conv2= (Convolution3D(32, 3, 3, 3, activation='relu', 
border_mode='same', name='conv1'))(input_1)

input_2= conv2.output

lstm2=(ConvLSTM2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3),
padding='same', return_sequences=True))(input_2)

conv3= (Convolution3D(32, 3, 3, 3, activation='relu', 
border_mode='same', name='conv1'))(input_2)

input_3= conv3.output

lstm3=(ConvLSTM2D(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3),
padding='same', return_sequences=True))(input_3)
```

then I will merge the LSTM together.
I am getting many errors such as 'Layer conv1 has no inbound nodes'.
Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing concepts from the [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). In your case, it seems like you are missing the `Input` layer that a functional model requires. You also don't need to get `.output` to link layers, just calling them is enough `lstm3(conv3)`.

Comment: Actually when I fixed the input that you told me about. The code worked fine. Thank you so much